# How to have the value of a One to One relationship returned after a Get with JPA?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

my main problem is that when I do a get "/users" request on the API I'm developing I don't get the data stored in my One to one relationship:

to make it clear here is an example of the response I get from my request:

```
{"id":1,"name":"toto Toto","email":"toto@test.fr","username":"toto","role":{},...}
```

"role":{} is empty BUT I verified that there is a role associated with this user in the database and in debug mode I can see the role is loaded as I want.
So the only problem is that JPA doesn't want to return the Role value when I return the whole User (even if Role is a part of User).

One of my ideas was to rewrite the converter object to Json but from what I saw on the internet it's quite a pain and moreover it should work without doing it, so I must have made a mistake somewhere but I can't find where...

If you have an idea please tell me :)

Here are my One-To-One and One-to-Many relationship for both User and Role :
User:

```
@OneToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name = "role_user",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
@NotNull
@JsonManagedReference
private Role role;
```

Role:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "role_user",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "role_id" ),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "user_id" ) )
@JsonBackReference
private List<User> user;
```

I'm new to stack overflow so I don't know if I gave enough information, if not please tell me what you want to know.

Thank you for your time.